# Keep Same Data When Page Refreshed Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm getting data on button click from WebAPI and navigate the component to other component to show this data and this trick is working fine for me but the issue is when I refresh the page my data is empty, Please provide me some solution or example to keep same data.
Thanks in advance

component.ts `//where I'm getting data onClick`

```
onSubmit(){
this.departmentService.GetDepartmentSearchResults(this.modelSearch1.value.Department, this.modelSearch1.value.Year, this.modelSearch1.value.No).subscribe(res => {
      this.objDepartmentsSearchedResults = res as DepartmentsSearchedResultsModel[];
      this.departmentService.objDepartmentsSearchedResults = this.objDepartmentsSearchedResults;
      this._router.navigate(['departments/search-results']);
    });
}
```

service.ts `//where I'm passing data to varaible`

```
objDepartmentsSearchedResults: DepartmentsSearchedResultsModel[];
```

Other component.ts `//where I want to show this data`

```
ngOnInit(){
    console.log("results listing : ", this.departmentServices.objDepartmentsSearchedResults);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something called localStorage which allows you to save your data in any component and use it in any other component.

So in your case, you can just put the data of the form in local storage and use it in another component.

Please refer this on how to use it.

**https://medium.com/@tiagovalverde/how-to-save-your-app-state-in-localstorage-with-angular-ce3f49362e31**

Comment: I've configure it but how can I get item from it?

Comment: localStorage.getItem("some-key");

Comment: Assuming its a form so you will have multiple fields. Just assign a key to those fields (one key for one field) while saving in localStorage then use the getItem function as Blair said

Comment: localStorage.setItem("key", "value_from_form");

Comment: did you imported import { StorageServiceModule } from ‘  ngx-webstorage-service’;

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localStorage/sessionStorage` to store and retrieve data.

But, best approach is to fulfill a route(page) data from the same page itself.

Let's say you are routing from

```
items(ItemListComponent) --> items/:id(ItemDetailsComponent)
```

You can pass item data associated with an id from `items` page (*ItemListComponent*). So *ItemDetailsComponent* may not need an additional call to get data.

- If the `items/:id` is loaded directly(by someone else) or refreshed, the data passed from `items` page is lost.
- So you have to have a condition to fetch the data if passed in data is undefined. You can do that since all you need is `:id`, that you already have as route param

As per your example consider passing **Department**, **Year**, **No** as route **query params**. If the data is passed from previous page, use that. Else do a server call with those query params(on refresh or when the page is loaded directly when someone else access that route)

**page1.component.ts**

```
onSubmit(){
  const {Department, Year, No} = this.modelSearch1.value;
  this._router.navigate([`departments/search-results?department=${Department}&year=${Year}&no=${No}`]);
}
```

**page2.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    const Department = params.get('department');
    const Year = params.get('year');
    const No = params.get('no');

    // make departmentServices call to get data
    ...
  });
}
```